# Serialize custom properties on a class that implements IEnumerable

Tags: c#, json.net

Currently, JSON.NET ignores all other properties on classes implementing IEnumerable and serializes the array.

How can I tell JSON.NET to serialize the custom properties? I'm trying to serialize the `PagedList<T>` implementation below:

```
public interface IPagedList : IEnumerable
{
    int PageIndex { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    int TotalCount { get; }
    int TotalPages { get; }
    bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
    bool HasNextPage { get; }
}

public interface IPagedList<T> : IPagedList, IList<T>
{
}

/// <summary>
/// A tried and tested PagedList implementation
/// </summary>
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
{
    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) :
        this(source.GetPage(pageIndex, pageSize), pageIndex, pageSize, source.Count()) { }

    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
    {
        Ensure.Argument.NotNull(source, "source");

        this.TotalCount = totalCount;
        this.TotalPages = totalCount / pageSize;

        if (totalCount % pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;

        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;

        this.AddRange(source.ToList());
    }

    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public bool HasPreviousPage { get { return (PageIndex > 0); } }
    public bool HasNextPage { get { return (PageIndex + 1 < TotalPages); } }
}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?  If so, please tell us what it was.  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue just now. Currently I'm thinking to just refactor it and have an "Items" property so the actual PagedList itself won't implement IEnumerable<T>. Does anyone else have a better solution?

Comment: @LeeGunn Your two options are either to add an Items property or implement a JsonConverter.  This is discussed below and also in the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up having to use a custom converter to do it.  My converter takes a list of type names to operate on rather than working globally.  I took your class and wrote a small console application that will run your class through the converter.  The magic is in the setup of the JsonSerializerSettings to use the EnumerableConverter class.  Once that's setup you must use the settings object in the SerializeObject calls.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pagedList = new PagedList<MyObject>(
                                new MyObject[] { 
                                    new MyObject { Foo = "Bar" }, 
                                    new MyObject { Foo = "Baz" } 
                                }, 0, 2, 2);
            Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pagedList));
            // Outputs: [{"Foo":"Bar"},{"Foo":"Baz"}]

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new List<JsonConverter>(
                                new[]{
                                    new EnumerableConverter(
                                       new []{"ConsoleApplication2.PagedList"}, 
                                              false)
                                })
            };
            Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pagedList, settings));
            // Outputs: 
            //{
            //   "PageIndex":0,
            //   "PageSize":2,
            //   "TotalCount":2,
            //   "TotalPages":1,
            //   "HasPreviousPage":false,
            //   "HasNextPage":false,
            //   "Capacity":4,
            //   "Count":2,
            //   "Items":[
            //      {
            //         "Foo":"Bar"
            //      },
            //      {
            //         "Foo":"Baz"
            //      }
            //   ]
            //}      
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPagedList : IEnumerable
    {
        int PageIndex { get; }
        int PageSize { get; }
        int TotalCount { get; }
        int TotalPages { get; }
        bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
        bool HasNextPage { get; }
    }

    public interface IPagedList<T> : IPagedList, IList<T>
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A tried and tested PagedList implementation
    /// </summary>
    public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
    {
        //public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) :
        //    this(source.GetPage(pageIndex, pageSize), pageIndex, pageSize, source.Count()) { }

        public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
        {
            //Ensure.Argument.NotNull(source, "source");

            this.TotalCount = totalCount;
            this.TotalPages = totalCount / pageSize;

            if (totalCount % pageSize > 0)
                TotalPages++;

            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.PageIndex = pageIndex;

            this.AddRange(source.ToList());
        }

        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int PageSize { get; private set; }
        public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public bool HasPreviousPage { get { return (PageIndex > 0); } }
        public bool HasNextPage { get { return (PageIndex + 1 < TotalPages); } }
    }

    public class EnumerableConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    {
        private IEnumerable<string> Types { get; set; }
        private bool IsCamelCase { get; set; }

        public EnumerableConverter(IEnumerable<string> types)
            : this(types, true)
        {
        }

        public EnumerableConverter(IEnumerable<string> types, bool isCamelCase)
        {
            if (types == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
            Types = types;
            IsCamelCase = isCamelCase;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            var foundInnerEnumerable = false;
            foreach (var property in value.GetType().GetProperties()) {
                try {
                    var propVal = property.GetValue(value, null);
                    foundInnerEnumerable |= propVal is IEnumerable;
                    writer.WritePropertyName(NameFor(property.Name));
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, propVal);
                }
                catch (System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException) { 
                    // Ignore properties such as Item on List<T>
                }
            }
            if (!foundInnerEnumerable) {
                writer.WritePropertyName(NameFor("Items"));
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)value) {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
                }
                writer.WriteEndArray();
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        private string NameFor(string value)
        {
            if (!IsCamelCase) return value;
            return value[0].ToString().ToLowerInvariant() + value.Substring(1);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return Types.Any(t => objectType.FullName.StartsWith(t));
        }
    }

}
```